# Where on Github, or elsewhere, can I find the code for core-blocks?

Tags: block-editor

Apparently, at one time, there was a directory of core-blocks for building Gutenberg templates on GitHub, but I'm not finding it anywhere. I talking about `core/paragraph`, etc.

```
    array( 'core/paragraph', array(
        'placeholder' => 'Content goes here',
    ) ),
    array( 'core/image', array(
        ...
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/block-library/src

Comment: You should post that as an answer

Answer (score 8):

The core blocks appear to be defined in the Gutenberg repository on Github, in the `block-library` package here: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/block-library/src.